# Installing Ports for Arduino Nano on Mac OS X Yosemite

Tags: osx

Just starting with Arduino and have gotten stuck at the first hurdle: trying to connect an Arduino Nano with my Mac Book Pro which runs 10.10. I can't seem to find the right port as all suggestions have bluetooth in the name and none with USB anything. Also the post list does not change when I plug/unplug the Arduino. Looking at http://arduino.cc/en/guide/macOSX#toc3 it says that I need to install FTDI software to get the USB port to show, however, having done this it still does not work. Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Calum

Comment: If this is a genuine nano from arduino.cc then the FTDI driver is what you need; if it is from someone else it could require a different driver or not be functional at all.  If you do apple-about_this_mac-system_report you can see a list of USB devices, if you can find the VID/PID associated with your board and add it to your question or do a web search on it that would help a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Had exactly the same problem. Also using 10.10 and just got an Arduino. What worked for me was using a different cable. The one that came with my Arduino Uno only provided power not data. If you have a printer, it might have the right cable, just test it quickly.

Edit: In addition, whilst trying to find solutions, I also installed 64bit mac FTDIUSBSerialDriver_v2_2_18.dmg. I'm not sure if it made a difference. As after installing it and using the original cable the problem persisted.

Comment: Hopefully that was not an official board but a knock-off, if the cable it came with was bad.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a USB hub? I had problems with my MBP when the Arduino was on a hub. Attached directly to the mac it was fine.